# How to overload a function with multiple parameters correctly in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, overloading

I'm trying to define a function `includes`, that works for both, arrays and strings.

But I'm having trouble typing it correctly. If I understand correctly, overloading is possible using unions. So this is what I'm trying:

```js
// Declarations
export function includes<T>(arr: T[], el: T): boolean;
export function includes(str: string, substr: string): boolean;
// Implementation
export function includes<T>(arr: T[] | string, el: T | string) {
  return arr.indexOf(el) !== -1;
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype
```

which makes sense, because if `arr` is of type `T`, `el` shouldn't be of type `string`, but the unions makes that a "possibility".

So how would I correctly type the implementation here to say that the arguments may be either `T[] and T` or `string and string`?

Comment: I would type `el` as `any` in the implementation. It's not part of your public API anyway.

Comment: Okeey, certainly possible here, but assuming that the function would return `T` in case 1 and `string` in case 2, then I'd want to keep the type safety. So then I'd have to type it correctly. How would I do that

Comment: You could still use any as the return type.

Comment: Sure, but then I'd lose the type information

Comment: You would not lose type information on TS level, the overloaded declarations would act as guards here. Should be fine with `any` in the actual implementation.

Comment: And if you want it all in one declaration: `function includes<T>(a: T extends string ? string : T[], b: T): boolean ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not safe to call `arr.indexOf(el)` where `arr` is `T | string[]` and `el` is `T | string` because the compiler isn't sure that you're not mismatching them, as in `"typescript".indexOf(2)` or `[1,2,3].indexOf("rip")`.  The fact that the type of `arr` and `el` should be *correlated* is hard to express in TypeScript.  In the absence of  [correlated record types (see microsoft/TypeScript#30581)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)], it's reasonable to do less type-safe things like use `any` or other workarounds inside the implementation, since the overload call signatures prevent any such unsoundness from being visible to callers of your function.

However, in your case, I'd be inclined to use the following implementation signature:

```
export function includes<T>(arr: { indexOf(x: T): number }, el: T) {
    return arr.indexOf(el) !== -1;
}
```

Here, all we care about is the fact that `arr` has an `indexOf()` method that takes a value of some type `T` and returns a `number`, and that `el` is a `T`.  This makes `arr.indexOf(el)` compile with no error no matter what, and it's compatible with both of the overload call signatures.  In fact, you might even want to ditch the overloads and just use the above definition, unless you have some reason why `includes()` should be restricted to `string`-or-`Array<T>` inputs.  Let's make sure it behaves:

```
includes("typescript", "rip"); // okay
includes([1, 2, 3], 2); // okay

includes("typescript", 2); // error
includes([1, 2, 3], "rip"); // error
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PQKmwAgEQUwYwDYEMBOSAuBLA9gOwM4BQMAHgA7YroQBmArrnFnhJownQCYz4A8AKgD4AFKhQAuCPwDaAXQA0EGAkn8AlJIBG2bAhhJcAbmLlK1eo2a5W7Lj2H50EiI5RsA5ovx1Nrya48NCG1dfSNCcAgASQBbMj0YmFx0DBxcEwoqWgYmNJtEOz4hURRnAG8bbhIAeRphElUg3DoYzRgUCABfRWVGiDLCCCGIFBh0OhRrMQA6Nira4WU1CABCAF41iABaAEZjTrBBjLNsyzy2Au4ikTFJCrnSBYapJpa2ju6lFRf+weHR8aTCAzB41OpLVYbbZ7QidQiEC4cK7CABE6AAnmQeHA3GR0CjFCjcSi1IYIJFsABrJDohG2ZHSHaKABMigAzAoIMzSeTIFSafDEYVURisfgcZg8QSuTzIu0UJQ6Zd7IyWezOUTJSSyXLSoqgA)